# Azure - SDK 2.0 to 2.3 - Will they run side by side?

Tags: azure

I am looking to install the newest version of the Azure SDK which is version 2.3.  Can this run side by side with Azure SDK 2.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you install the SDK, there're two things which gets installed -

1. Some libraries & helper utilities.
2. Emulators (compute and storage).

At any point of time, the emulator you have is that of the latest version. So if you have installed SDK 2.0 and then install SDK 2.3, you will have the libraries & utilities for both 2.0 and 2.3 so that you can reference libraries from that SDK in your application and use the utilities there but the emulator would be of version 2.3.

For example, please take a look at the screenshot below. I have SDK 2.3 installed on my computer.

[image]

Comment: Is this still the case?