# Side by side installation of different Azure emulators

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-emulator

As far as I know, it is possible to have [multiple Azure SDK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112137/azure-sdk-2-0-to-2-3-will-they-run-side-by-side) (*2.1*, *2.2*, *2.3* etc.) on a single machine, and reference specific versions of the Azure assemblies as desired (from the Visual Studio project or so).

Though, how to manage different installations of **Azure Emulators** (*Compute*, *Storage*)? Is it possible to install more of them, then choose a specific one - when debugging the piece of software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to install more of them, then choose a specific one -
>   when debugging the piece of software?

AFAIK, this is not possible. At any given point of time, there can be only one version of emulator installed on a machine.